# Git problem: error: src refspec origin does not match any

Tags: git, julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

Any info I have found in similar threads could not help me solve the problem.

Basically, I am working on a git project. My usual way of working have been:

```
git checkout -b new_branch   #Create a new branch
```

I program in Julia programming language, using the Juno IDE within Atom. I have a Julia package in the "dev" folder (for those into Julia developing). I make a couple of changes to the code. Atom/Juno lets me commit them. When I am done I go to gt and write

```
git push git_user_name origin
```

This is the routine someone told me, and while I am not very familiar with git it has kinda always worked out. Until now, when I got this back:

```
error: src refspec origin does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:JuliaPackage/JuliaSubPackage.jl.git'
```

Only a week ago or so I did all this and it worked out. But now I get this error. Lots of online help threads seem to suggest that an initial commit is missing, but I have made several commits here.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be going on?

Comment: `git push username origin` is almost certainly wrong. What's probably right is `git push origin new_branch`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't commit anything, try this:

```
git add *
git commit -m "my commit" 
git push origin git_user_name //instead of git_user_name origin
```

Alternatively do a `git show-ref`, if you want to see all your refs.
Then you can do a `git push origin HEAD:<your_branch>`.

If this works you probably created a branch before pushing into master.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add some more Julia specific comments about a typical workflow (and assumes standard configuration of your git repository).

1. In Julia in package manager mode you write `dev YourPackage`
2. You go to `.julia/dev/YourPackage` folder
3. run a command `git remote -v`; make sure that you have the right to push to the `origin` (this might not true if you are trying to contribute to a package created by someone else who did not give you write rights to the repository)
4. run `git checkout -b your_branch`
5. Make your changes to the code
6. run `test YourPackage` in the package manager mode (so that you are sure that your changes pass the tests defined in the package)
7. commit the changes using `git add` and `git commit`
8. Run `git push --set-upstream origin your_branch` (this will fail if you do not have right to push to `origin` - see step 3. above); if the branch was created earlier on the remote and you just want to add some commits to it it is enough to just write `git push`
9. When you are happy with the changes and done with the development of the functionality then most likely you will want to:

   - squash merge the commits you made in your branch to master branch in the origin
   - optionally you can make a release of the package (then when you leave `dev` mode the package version including your changes will be available)
   - delete `your_branch` locally and in the `origin`
   - update `master` locally with the `master` from the `origin`

Comment: This worked!Not really sure how, but the "git push --set-upstream origin your_branch" seemed to do the trick. Thanks